# Configuration Options not set on rebuild - Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am dynamically adding the select options and also setting the config options, and performing a rebuild.

The options are appended fine, but the config options set are not getting reflected. The same config options are set fine on initial load but not when appending the options dynamically.

What could be the issue?

```
onEvent: function(dt)
{
    $.each(dt.lst, function(ind, ele)
    {
        var htm = '<option value="' + ele + '">' + ele + '</option>';
        $('#myMultiSelectId').append(htm);
    });

    $('#myMultiSelectId').multiselect({
        maxHeight: 300,
        includeResetOption: true,
        resetText: 'Deselect All'
    });

    $('#myMultiSelectId').multiselect('rebuild');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Documentation](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options) there is an example that explicity uses the `.multiselect('setOptions', options)` in conjuntion with `rebuild` for this purpose, so try next code:

```
onEvent: function(dt)
{
    $.each(dt.lst, function(ind, ele)
    {
        var htm = '<option value="' + ele + '">' + ele + '</option>';
        $('#myMultiSelectId').append(htm);
    });

    $('#myMultiSelectId').multiselect('setOptions', {
        maxHeight: 300,
        includeResetOption: true,
        resetText: 'Deselect All'
    });

    $('#myMultiSelectId').multiselect('rebuild');
}
```

Alternatively, you can `destroy` the multiselect and create it again, like this:

```
onEvent: function(dt)
{
    $('#myMultiSelectId').multiselect('destroy');

    $.each(dt.lst, function(ind, ele)
    {
        var htm = '<option value="' + ele + '">' + ele + '</option>';
        $('#myMultiSelectId').append(htm);
    });

    $('#myMultiSelectId').multiselect({
        maxHeight: 300,
        includeResetOption: true,
        resetText: 'Deselect All'
    });
}
```

Comment: I have added another alternative, use destroy and construct it again... Anyway, can you provide a minimal snippet showing the issue if the last alternative don't solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Smania, it worked. Destroy does the trick. rebuild is not required in this case.